# How to use lazy loading + sort in p-Table using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

i have used lazy loading in my application and also i want to use the sorting of the items.
If i don't use lazy loading it works fine, but i want the application to work in both lazy loading and sorting. Can anyone help me to solve this.

DEMO:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ya2md7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thats stackblitz is sorted so what is the problem?

Comment: @Antoniossss: No that is not sorted, if i remove lazy load and click on header, then the data gets sorted, as in this https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot sort elements that does not exists. Either load everything, sort and then display, or let your backend serve sorted and paginated data for lazy loading.

Thats how it normally works (letter option)

Comment: but i want the data which is visible in pagination to be sorted

Comment: But it will be only sorted localy - in a scope of current page

Comment: ya that is what i want

Comment: Then just sort it on page load. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: i mean when the page loads and i click on headers, it must sort me the data present in that page

Comment: this works fine if lazy load is not there, with lazy loading it doesnt work

Comment: You mean you want something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qquyv1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: ya, that was what i was actually looking for, thank you soo much but the thing here with my lazy loading in my application is that, if i remove the get method then the data wont load, if i give the data it doesnt work but i get sortField name n al in console

Comment: I simply have no clue what is your problem, sorry

Comment: sorry to interrupt you, i am using pagination as wel, but here if i go to sort items in 2nd page, rest data in page1 goes off

Answer (score 3):

The **LazyLoadEvent** that is fired by the grid (When pagination is on) holds properties for the requested column to sort by. As long as you add the  **pSortableColumn** attribute to the **th** tags.

I think the direction property is also there with a value of -1 or +1 value.  So you can pick these values up as part of the LazyLoadEvent handler and pass it to your backend (You just interpret what you get from the event into what your back end needs).  I have to convert -1 into 'DESC' for Descending.